# Can't install Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I am sorry if I'm asking this in wrong place but since it's about the coding IDE I don't know where else to go.

I just can not install Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 on my **fresh** Windows 10 Pro installation (only Office 2013 installed) and **fresh** Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

The error as follows:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Fails to install]

And once this error occurs, Visual Studio no longer works.

I could consider about skipping this update but I need to install Mobile Programming Packs (Xamarin) and they require Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to be installed first.

I have searched the net about the error code "0x80070490" but nothing came up related to Visual Studio.

Since the whole log file is too big to fit here, these are the lines contains "error" phrase:

```
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i325: Registering dependency: {4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.sdk_tools35,v11, package: sdk_tools35
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i325: Registering dependency: {4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.CodeAnalysis_x86_enu,v14, package: RoslynLanguageServices
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {6C1985E7-E1C5-3A95-86EF-2C62465F15C3}, version: 14.0.23107, package: RoslynLanguageServicesResMsi
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i325: Registering dependency: {4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3} on package provider: {6C1985E7-E1C5-3A95-86EF-2C62465F15C3}, package: RoslynLanguageServicesResMsi
[1890:1C78][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i304: Verified existing payload: VSSecondaryInstaller_box at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1DC8404EE32E731EC1B170A992B7208CE63094E7\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe.
[1538:0C6C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin for secondary installer
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Checking to see if the secondary installer pipe should be created
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Creating secondary installer pipe: {2b9a38d8-87f0-4279-b481-8ac30b840d80}
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[1538:0B24][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Begin connecting secondary installer pipe
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i301: Applying execute package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1DC8404EE32E731EC1B170A992B7208CE63094E7\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1DC8404EE32E731EC1B170A992B7208CE63094E7\packages\SecondaryInstaller\SecondaryInstaller.exe" /q /BurnBundleProviderKey {4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3} /lcid 1033 /BaseDirectory "J:\\" /localfeed "C:\Users\Roni\AppData\Local\Temp\98110090.xml" /FeedRegistryKey "Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\vs\community" /primarylog "C:\Users\Roni\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20160419125540.log" /skuSpecificHKLMHive Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 /launchaction Modify  /installitems VSU_14.0.25123;AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RTMV1_5.2.60322.1;JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25205;JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25205 /potentialcachecleanup ++VSU_14.0.25123++VSU_14.0.25115++VSU_14.0.25029++VSU_14.0.25008++VSU_14.0.24912++VSU_14.0.24720++VSU_14.0.24627;++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RTMV1_5.2.60322.1++AppInsightsToolsRTMCheck_HiddenV1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV2_4.0.51117.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV3_4.0.51203.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV4_4.1.60107.3++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV5_4.2.60128.3++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenV6_4.3.60222.2++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2CTPV1_5.0.60115.1++AppInsightsToolsVisualStudio_HiddenVSU2RCV1_5.1.60222.1;++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25205++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV2++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV2++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV3++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV3++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV4++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV4++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25123A++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25123A;++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25205++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenRTM++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV2++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV2++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV3++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV3++JavaScriptProjectSystem_HiddenV4++JavaScriptLanguageService_HiddenV4++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25008++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25029++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25115++JavaScriptProjectSystem_Hidden_14.0.25123A++JavaScriptLanguageService_Hidden_14.0.25123A /Pipe {2b9a38d8-87f0-4279-b481-8ac30b840d80} {77527ce8-5c43-4712-b947-859343f965c5} -burn.ancestors={4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3}'
[1890:1C78][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i304: Verified existing payload: vs_postclean_vs at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9735CABA-17F0-3C02-B41B-5A770280AD63\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PostClean_vs.exe.
[1538:0C6C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1890:1C78][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i304: Verified existing payload: community_finalizer at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9E99CC49-D305-4D42-AC34-6C732062B142}v14.0.23107\packages\community_finalizer.msi.
[1538:0C6C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1890:1C78][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i304: Verified existing payload: ModernBlend_finalizer at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{93A31A4A-197C-43F0-9687-7FFC47C33D44}v14.0.23107\packages\ModernBlend_finalizer.msi.
[1538:0C6C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1890:1C78][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i304: Verified existing payload: VSGraphics_VSGA_finalizer_msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{919C67A9-2DE8-4929-A910-CB85E009B5CB}v14.0.23107\packages\VSGraphics_VSGA_finalizer.msi.
[1538:0C6C][2016-04-19T12:56:04]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1538:0B24][2016-04-19T12:56:05]i000: MUX:  Finished connecting secondary installer pipe
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:56:22]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:56:29]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:56:30]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=Visual Studio Update Prerequisite
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:56:44]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=KB3022398
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:57:44]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=KB3022398LP
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:57:52]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=KB3022398
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:58:46]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, Inner=
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:58:46]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Developer Analytics Tools v5.2.0, Inner=
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:58:52]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=JavaScript Language Service for Visual Studio, Inner=
[1538:18B0][2016-04-19T12:59:09]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=JavaScript Project System for Visual Studio, Inner=
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T13:00:02]e000: Error 0x80048646: Process returned error: 0x80048646
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T13:00:02]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 988090456  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 461045848
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageComplete for secondary installer
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Disconnecting secondary installer pipe
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80048646 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147187130 (0x80048646), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]w350: Applied non-vital package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, encountered error: 0x80048646. Continuing...
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_postclean_vs
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i301: Applying execute package: vs_postclean_vs, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9735CABA-17F0-3C02-B41B-5A770280AD63\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PostClean_vs.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9735CABA-17F0-3C02-B41B-5A770280AD63\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PostClean_vs.exe" /community /repair /log C:\Users\Roni\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20160419125540_017_vs_postclean_vs.log'
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_postclean_vs MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i319: Applied execute package: vs_postclean_vs, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: community_finalizer
[1890:12D0][2016-04-19T13:00:02]i301: Applying execute package: community_finalizer, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9E99CC49-D305-4D42-AC34-6C732062B142}v14.0.23107\packages\community_finalizer.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1" SKIP_APPID_SETUP=""'
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:17]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: community_finalizer MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1503232  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:17]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:RollbackCleanup Restart:None
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:17]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1538:039C][2016-04-19T13:00:17]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
```

Comment: You may like to also ask at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

Comment: this is ridiculous

Comment: did you solve the problem? i am hitting the similar problem here.

Comment: similar problem pls answer if u find it

Comment: same problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I also had the error **"missing or damaged package KB3022398"** when trying to upgrade VS2015 CE Update 2 to Update 3.
I tried to completely uninstall VS2015 Community Edition, plus removing things from the following, but it still didn't work:

- **C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Local\Temp**
- **C:\ProgramData\Package Cache (though I don't quite recommend this one; these packages are used when you uninstall various features of VS2015 from Control Panel)**
- **C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio**
- folders **VisualStudio**, **VisualStudio Services**, **VSCommon**, **VsGraphics** from **C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft**
- **C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015** (I didn't try this one, but I don't think this is the culprit since it has to do with your themes and projects)

Other things I tried that didn't work:

- Using [Web Installer for Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3 – Free](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x409) (vs_community.exe)
- Using [ISO for Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3 – Free](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409)
  I also verified integrity of downloaded ISO and it was ok (you have to download [Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290) and check SHA-1 for your ISO and see if it corresponds to the one described at **[1]**)
- Using vs_community.exe /Layout  (from Web Installer, also from mounted ISO)
  More details at **[2]** and **[3]**
  e.g.

  ```
  vs_community.exe /PromptRestart /CustomInstallPath "<visual studio installation directory" /L <path for log file> /InstallSelectableItems VSU;VS_SDK_Breadcrumb_GroupV5;NativeLanguageSupport_VCV1;NativeLanguageSupport_MFCV1;NativeLanguageSupport_XPV1;PythonToolsForVisualStudio;WebToolsV1;PowerShellToolsV1;GitHubVSV1;OfficeDeveloperToolsV1`
  ```
- Applying Update 3 while I had VS2015 CE Update 2 installed

What worked for me:

- Start -> Type "Settings" -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Reset this PC (with apps deletion and everything)

My guess is that it has something to do with Registry + leftovers in installation drive.

What you can try:

- Start -> Type "Settings" -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Reset this PC (with apps deletion and everything)
- I recommend using [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/download-professional-version.php) since it also helps you to delete leftovers from Registry (you can also use other applications, this is just a recommendation).
  This would be an alternative to "Reset this PC" (I'm not yet sure if it will quite work).
  The idea is that it worked on the same computer with fresh install of Windows 10 Pro (no previous installation of Visual Studio 2015 CE).
- Uninstalling using vs_community.exe /Uninstall /Force (more details at **[4]**)
- Installing using **Web Installer** or **ISO** of [Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146) and then apply using [Web Installer of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) or [ISO of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=708984)
- You can also take a look with [Autoruns for Windows v13.62](https://technet.microsoft.com/ro-ro/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and see if there's anything related to Visual Studio. If yes, then try delete those keys using regedit

[1] [Visual Studio 2015 ISO Files SHA-1 Hashes](https://www.visualstudio.com/productinfo/vs2015-sha-vs)
[2] [Automated Installation Options for Visual Studio 2015](http://timsneath.com/visual-studio-2015-installation-options/)
[3] [How to fix stuck Visual Studio Community installation problem](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2015/08/solving-installation-is-stuck-problem-in-visual-studio-community-edition/)
[4] [Removing Visual Studio components left behind after an uninstall](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/)